# Does Java sit in Type-0 lavel of Chomsky Hierarchy?

Tags: java, chomsky-hierarchy

Does Java sit in Type-0 lavel of Chomsky Hierarchy?

As I know, C++ template is Turing-Complete, so C++ sits in Type-0 of Chomsky Hierarchy. Java also have Generic, Does Java sit in Type-0 lavel of Chomsky Hierarchy?

Comment: Java generics have been proved to be Turing complete as well. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.05274.pdf

Comment: So java also sits in Type-0 of Chomsky Hierarchy? @marstran

Comment: No idea, never heard of it